# display records using textbox from sql database

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, combobox, textbox

This is my code for displaying records from database to combo box but, when I edit the code and make it for textbox, `.DataSource` and `.ValueMember` are not working for textboxes.

```
 Dim sqlconn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    sqlconn.ConnectionString = "server = SKPI-APPS1;" & _
    "Database = EOEMS;integrated security=true"

    Dim dt As New DataTable

    sqlconn.Open()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblOfficeEquipmentProfile", sqlconn)
    da.Fill(dt)
    cmbLocationCode.DataSource = dt
    cmbLocationCode.ValueMember = "OE_ID"
    sqlconn.Close()
```

What is the corresponding code for displaying data from database using textboxes?

Comment: Exactly the same code. You just need to extract the data from the "da" datatable and put it into a text box.

Comment: using textboxes? m mean to say u need to fetch data from database and diplay it in a textbox?

Comment: @PraveenNambiar yes sir fetching data from database and display it to the textbox

Comment: @CathalMF i tried editing the code for comboboxes but .datasource and .valuemember are not for textboxes, only works for comboboxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simple do this:

```
yourTextBox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("ColumnName").ToString()
```

Comment: i just used this code

Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblOfficeEquipmentProfile", sqlconn)
        da.Fill(dt)
        txtName.Text = dt.Rows(0)("OE_Name").ToString()

Answer (score 0):

There is no property like datasource,valuemember and display name will not availiable. please refer this link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox_properties(v=vs.90).aspx

You only able to assign values from database or local assigment. You should do in the following ways . Assume that if you have **txtUserName**  textbox , you should assign the follwing way

> txtLocationCode=dt.rows[0]["column name"].tostring()

There is no property datasource is not availiable since it not collection object. It holds only one column value from database.

**Update :**

```
Public Sub PopulateOeqProfileForm()
Dim sqlconn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    sqlconn.ConnectionString = "server = SKPI-APPS1;" & _
   "Database = EOEMS;integrated security=true"

    Dim dt As New DataTable

    sqlconn.Open()

     Dim SelectCommand As New SqlClient.SqlCommand (SELECT OE_ID FROM tblOfficeEquipmentProfile, sqlconn)

   txtOEID.Text = Cstr(SelectCommand.ExecuteScalar()) 
   sqlconn.Close() 
End Sub
```

Hope this helps

Comment: id revised my code for the corresponding column and tables names kindly check sir

Comment: you want to store only one column value or multiple column values

Comment: Then you can use excutescalar function instead of SqlDataAdapter. I will edit post to scalar function. Since usage of datatable will costs performance.

Comment: Please check my answer i have revised the answer

Comment: please remove line  the da.fill(dt) and then try

Answer (score 0):

it does not diplay data sir

```
 Public Sub PopulateOeqProfileForm()
    Dim sqlconn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    sqlconn.ConnectionString = "server = SKPI-APPS1;" & _
    "Database = EOEMS;integrated security=true"

    Dim dt As New DataTable

    sqlconn.Open()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblOfficeEquipmentProfile", sqlconn)
    da.Fill(dt)
    txtOEID.Text = dt.Rows(0)("OE_ID").ToString()
    sqlconn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: what do you mean how much is the row count?

Comment: Meaning : When you are filling it in the Datatable what is the row count. dt.Rows.count..

Comment: Check whether OE_ID for row 1 has values or not. Or is it just Empty or null